# How to easily retrieve all or some of my external IP Addresses (on Android device)?

Tags: android, ip-address, p2p, hole-punching, wan

As I understood,
In order to initialize P2P connectivity via hole-punching, a device should reside in a non-symmetric NAT (which basically also implies single WAN\External IP Address for outgoing traffic).

I can not find an android app (kind of a little tester app, to open when I'm inside a LAN) that tells what are all or some of my WAN\External IP Addresses.
All apps on Play that I found show me only one External IP Address, even though I test it from Symmetric NATs with multiple WAN\External Addresses.

An easy and quick suggestion would be nice (surfing to multiple "whatismyip" sites each time I want to test it is not easy nor elegant\quick).

Comment: you can get only 1 external IP at a time, as the IP is recognized on the server, to which you are making requests. Therefore, you can try making multiple requests to the server and hoping that they would be sent from different IP addresses.

Comment: That's what I'm searching for. an app that does this for me. or a site that tries several times to make my browser refresh and auto-updates with all the ip-addresses it found along all those requests it made me to do. but I did not find something that does this. I guess I'll write something for my own.

Comment: I've made an android application that does this work, and it looks good. tested it from several Symmetric NATs and seems to show their WANs IPs.
I uploaded it today to Play and it is now being reviewed. I'll post an answer to this topic with a link to my app when it will be approved.

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written an Android App that make multiple requests to multiple servers,
and prints the External IPs it used in the requests.
I tested it from several Symmetric NAT networks and it seems to work properly.
That's what I needed.

If someone is interested, I called it "External IPs Revealer \ Internet Checker":
[App on Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=shalev.apps.internetchecker)

Answer (score 1):

Some DNS servers support dynamic queries that return the sender's public IP, which can be used for this purpose:

`dig -4 +short A myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com`

`dig -4 TXT +short o-o.myaddr.l.google.com @ns1.google.com`

For a more detailed explanation what it does see [How does dig find my WAN-IP-adress? What is “myip.opendns.com” doing?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/335371/182322)